# Pointer to ICMPHeader

Tags: c, network-programming, pcap

I am reading packets in pcap format, and have determined that some have the protocol ICMP. I think that if that's the case, the ICMP header immediately follows the IP header. However, I get the wrong ICMP type (echo reply, request) for each of my results. I.e, here is the correct output for one such packet which has an echo reply:

```
Packet number: 2  Packet Len: 74

Ethernet Header
    Dest MAC: 0:2:2d:90:75:89
    Source MAC: 0:6:25:78:c4:7d
    Type: IP

IP Header
    TOS: 0xff
    TTL: 52
    Protocol: ICMP
    Checksum: Incorrect (0x5565)
    Sender IP: 66.94.230.35
    Dest IP: 192.168.1.102

ICMP Header
    Type: Reply
```

I know that echo reply has a code of 8, but instead of that I get a 0, indicating "request", and this happens for all packets when I try to get the type. I feel that I may be pointing my ICMP header to the wrong location following the IP header. My IP information though is correct. Here is how I am adjusting the pointers to the IP and ICMP headers:

```
EtherHeader *eth = (EtherHeader *)packet; 
IPHeader *iph;
TCPHeader *tcp;
ICMPHeader *icm;
---
ipLen = ntohs(iph->totLen * 4);
if(iph->protocol == ICMP) {
  icm = (ICMPHeader *)(packet + ETHER_SIZE + (ntohs(iph->totLen))); 
  printf("%d\n", icm->type);;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with how I am setting my pointer to the ICMP header?

Here are my headers for IP and ICMP:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) IPHeader {
   #if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __LITTLE_ENDIAN__
   uint8_t hdrLen:4;
   uint8_t version:4;
   #else
   uint8_t version:4;
   uint8_t hdrLen:4;
   #endif
   uint8_t TOS;
   uint16_t totLen;
   uint16_t id;
   uint16_t offset;
   #define DF 0x4            
   #define MF 0x2           
   #define OFF 0 
   uint8_t TTL;
   uint8_t protocol;
   uint16_t checksum;
   struct in_addr srcIP;
   struct in_addr destIP; 
}IPHeader; 

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) ICMPHeader {
   uint8_t type;
}ICMPHeader;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the control message type numbers is backwards:

> I know that echo reply has a code of 8, but instead of that I get a 0, indicating "request",

The correct values are:

```
0    Echo Reply
....
8    Echo Request
```

[**Internet Control Message Protocol - Control Messages**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Control_messages)

---

Also, although this doesn't appear to be used, you have an order of operations problem here - you can't do anything with the value until you change its byte order:

```
ntohs(iph->totLen * 4);
```

needs to be

```
ntohs(iph->totLen) * 4;
```

---

Comment: That gives me a segmentation fault. Furthermore, I always get a 0 for any other approach I use, even though some of them have to be 8. I have tried both hdrLen and totLen. It seems the IHL field of the IPv4 header is the length of the [IPv4 header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header#Header). Is that what I should be using instead of totLen, and is that also what I should use for the length of the checksum?

Comment: Yes, use your hdrLen field, not totLen.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that echo reply has a code of 8, but instead of that I get a 0,

No it doesn't. ICMP echo reply has a type of 0. type 8 is Echo (request).

See e.g. [this](http://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xhtml)

Comment: "code" really isn't the right word here - "type" is. "codes" are a sub-value of "types".